# Firestore naming - should I name a document based on the names of other documents?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Lets say I want to implement a chat app where:

1. There's a collection for users
2. There's a collection for chats

Lets say there are **two users**, each with documents ids (names): **ABC** and **XYZ**.
Now I create a single document (or collection) that holds the **chat data for those two users**, what would be a better approach (and why)?

1. Name it **ABC_XYZ** so that it would be easy to query for it
2. Let Firestore name it (**arbitrary ID**) and keep the two users IDs in that document

Comment: Both would work, and neither seems pertinently better than the other. I'd give both of them a try, and then decide which you prefer.

Comment: As Frank commented, yep, give it a try and see which one is better for your use case.